# SQL Query in Excel shows blank for some values

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a data on a sheet on excel and I use SQL to query to get a dataset.
This is the column the query is returning.

[image: Sample Data]

However, only items on numeric format is shown, and if the item is alphanumeric, it is blank.  The resulting query is below:

[image]

I have formatted this column as a text and below is my connection string:

```
objConnectionXL.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

Used query string:

```
sQueryFilteredValues = "Select [Reference] From [Data$] Where " & sFilterCriteria
```

I also tried using the query string below but it resulted the same:

```
sQueryFilteredValues = "Select CSTR([Reference]) From [Data$] Where " & sFilterCriteria
```

Recordset:

```
objRecordsetXL.Open sQueryFilteredValues, objConnectionXL, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

Where: adOpenStatic = 3, adLockOptimistic = 3, adCmdText = &H1

And I use below to copy the recordset into Excel

```
rngRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset objRecordsetXL
```

How can I show alphanumeric items on the recordset as well? 
Thanks!

Comment: What's the `.NumberFormat` on these cells?

Comment: I've set the .NumberFormat to "@".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the range I am copying the query results to. Only the source range has the text format. The format of the range I am copying the query results to is in general, so I guess Excel automatically converts the data into a number, based on the first cell value.

I resolved this problem by changing the format into text.